# Cannot connect to any rdp session and cannot connect to microsoft edge

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server, windows-10

I have a problem with a client. I cannot connect to any RDP session while all my other clients can.
I also cannot connect to Microsoft Edge. I can connect to Google Chrome though.
I got the error: `An internal error has occurred` when connecting to my servers.
When connecting to my terminal server (ts.xxx.info) I get the error: `Remote Desktop cant find the computer "ts.xxx.info"`.

Any idea what the problem is and how to fix it? This problem is not because of my domain user account because it works on other computers.

Comment: Are your firewall settings set to default?

Comment: @zain.ali I turned all my firewalls off: domain netwerk, private network, guest or public network. But this still didnt work. I accepted remote desktop in the `allowed apps` still didnt work. I turned my settings back to recommended and it still doenst work.

Comment: Are the remote services started on the local PC?

Comment: @zain.ali I think so yes. But when i tried to run `net start temService` it gave the error: the service name is invalid??